# Xgboost installation on Mac

Tags: python, macos, xgboost

I am trying to install xgboost on my mac (10.12.5) and after several attempts I did not succeed. I follow different tuto trying to modifi gcc variable by adding gcc-6 but I have the same problem.

So what I did:

1. git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
2. cd xgboost; cp make/minimum.mk ./config.mk; make -j4

I have the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -DDISABLE_OPENMP -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
/usr/local/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -DDISABLE_OPENMP -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
/usr/local/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -DDISABLE_OPENMP -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api.o src/c_api/c_api.cc >build/c_api/c_api.d
/usr/local/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -DDISABLE_OPENMP -MM -MT build/c_api/c_api_error.o src/c_api/c_api_error.cc >build/c_api/c_api_error.d
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/g++: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/g++: No such file or directory
make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/g++: No such file or directory
make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
make: *** [build/c_api/c_api.o] Error 127
/bin/sh: /usr/local/bin/g++: No such file or directory
make: *** [build/c_api/c_api_error.o] Error 127
```

My gcc version is:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I really need your help. For the moment I use `pip install xgboost` to use the library but I know it's not the right way to use this library. 
Thank you for your help

ps: sorry if my english is not ok, i am not fluent

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker images helps the best in such cases since it encapsulates the environment. You can install Docker from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04). If you want to work using xgboost library, you can pull image using the following command,

```
docker pull datmo/xgboost:cpu
```

After this, you can run containers using this image and mount necessary files in order to run the same environment.

You can also use [datmo](https://datmo.com/) CLI in order to easily setup environment and also version control your machine learning models.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install xgboost on my mac by using conda.

Try "conda install py-xgboost". This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try This it worked for

```
$ brew install gcc-5
$ brew install cmake
$ pip install xgboost
```